# Oracle Form 10g/12c function SET_FIELD

Tags: oracle10g, oracle12c

Does `SET_FIELD` function exists in Oracle Form 10g or 12c?  I hardly find documentation for this function.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not.  I guess you are asking because it appears in a list of reserved words in the online help?  That is because there was once a built-in procedure of that name in an earlier version.  Use SET_ITEM_PROPERTY instead.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/264850-130496.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, Tony's answer is not correct, in fact, in Oracle Forms 12c:

- SET_FIELD procedure cannot be found in Oracle Forms help, it's exists only in "PL/SQL and Oracle Forms Reserved Words" list, so SET_FIELD could be tracted as deprecated;
- At the same time SET_FIELD procedure still supported and works fine in Oracle Forms 12c (from working code). Oracle also mentioned SET_FIELD in [Upgrading Oracle Forms 6i to Oracle Forms
  12c](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/formsandreports/upgrade-forms/FSMFA.pdf):

  > Replace any references to obsolete logical
  >   and GUI attributes in SET_ITEM_PROPERTY, SET_FIELD, or DISPLAY_ITEM with
  >   an equivalent Visual Attribute.

P.S. Anyway, I personally going to replace all existing occurencies of SET_FIELD with SET_ITEM_PROPERTY :)